# In ConTeXt, what command resets the font size to "normal" after e.g. \tfa?

Tags: fontsize, context

I tried the following snippet just now:

```
\starttext
\tf  A quick brown fox \par
\tfc A quick brown fox \par
\tf  A quick brown fox \par
\tfb A quick brown fox \par
\tf  A quick brown fox \par
\tfa A quick brown fox \par
\tf  A quick brown fox \par
\stoptext
```

What I get out is the following:

[image]

I thought `\tf` is supposed to reset to normal size, according to [this page](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Basic_Text_Formatting). If `\tf` does not set the normal font size, what is the command that explicitly sets the normal font size, after you've e.g. done a `\tfa`?

Comment: Perhaps see also http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Font_Switching and http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb28-2/tb89mahajan.pdf.

Comment: Do you want a technical answer here (what `\tf` is defined to do) or a 'concepts' one (how it's supposed to be handled)? The detail of what `\tf` does is clear to the non-ConTeXt but TeX-experienced person, but the concepts will need a proper expert! (Hopefully one will be along soon.)

Comment: I read both those references already. Describing \tf as "normal size" led me to believe that it changes to the normal font size, but obviously it doesn't.  I suppose the remedy is to always wrap any non-standard font size text so that the document will return to the normal size text outside a group. Is this the only way to do it or is there a command that actually returns to the normal font size?

Comment: Did you see that part about 'small pieces of text': these commands don't set the baseline skip so are not meant for entire paragraph blocks.

Comment: `\tfa` etc. are not meant to be used for entire paragraphs. Just like `\bf` etc., in plain TeX, you should use them inside groups. If you want to explicitly set the font back to the "normal" font, you need to use `\setupbodyfont[reset]` or `\setupbodyfont[reset, 11pt]`

Comment: @Aditya I think you should turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Aditya All true but it is notable that the way the docs read you might imagine `\tf` resets the size, whereas tracing  it is clear it resets everything but size! (One could define `\tftext` or similar to do exactly that.)

Answer (score 4):

Aditya's comment above:

> `\tfa` etc. are not meant to be used for entire paragraphs. Just like `\bf` etc., in plain TeX, you should use them inside groups. If you want to explicitly set the font back to the "normal" font, you need to use `\setupbodyfont[reset]` or `\setupbodyfont[reset, 11pt]`

Answer (score 3):

Use `\restoreglobalbodyfont`:

```
\starttext
\tf  A quick brown fox \par
\tfc A quick brown fox \par
\restoreglobalbodyfont  A quick brown fox \par
\tfb A quick brown fox \par
\restoreglobalbodyfont  A quick brown fox \par
\tfa A quick brown fox \par
\restoreglobalbodyfont A quick brown fox \par
\stoptext
```

Source: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2005/009906.html